# Reload DataTable bound to Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I want to display a SQL table in my WPF Datagrid, writing SQL query at runtime.
I've built my View (simplified) and ViewModel associated:

View:

-----------------MyDataGrid.xaml-----------------

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CurrentSqlGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentDataTable,Mode=OneWay}"  
          Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  IsReadOnly="True" />
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxSql" Height="120" Grid.Row="1" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

-----------------MyDataGrid.cs-----------------

```
public partial class MyDataGrid : UserControl
{
    private SqlDataGridViewModel sqlDataGridViewModel;

    public MyDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sqlDataGridViewModel = new SqlDataGridViewModel();
        this.DataContext = sqlDataGridViewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sqlDataGridViewModel.FillDataTableWithQuery(TextBoxSql.Text);          
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

-----------------SqlDataGridViewModel.cs-----------------

```
public class SqlDataGridViewModel 
{
    private DataTable _dataTable;
    private SqlDataAdapter _adapter;

    public DataTable CurrentDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _dataTable = value;
        }
    }

    public SqlDataGridViewModel()
    {
        _dataTable = new DataTable("QUERY");
        FillDataTableWithQuery("SELECT TOP 500 * FROM XUSER");           
    }

    public void FillDataTableWithQuery(string query)
    {
        CurrentDataTable.Reset();
        CurrentDataTable.Clear();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(SessionProvider.Instance.currentConnectionString))
            {
                _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
                _adapter.Fill(CurrentDataTable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MartuLogger.Instance.Error("Exception in SqlDataGridViewModel :" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution display me first DataTable of first query.

But when I write another SQL query, I call `FillDataTableWithQuery("SELECT * from another_table")` and Datagrid clears all rows but it doesn't load new columns and new rows! (only display old columns!). In debug, the `CurrentDataTable` contains new query's results....  Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**
With Help of Faisal Hafeez we 've found this solution:

Xaml and code behind are the same. it work with OneWay and TwoWay mode.

My view model becomes :

```
public class SqlDataGridViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataTable _dataTable;
    private SqlDataAdapter _adapter;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChange(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    public DataTable CurrentDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _dataTable = value;
            //NotifyPropertyChange("CurrentDataTable");
        }
    }

    public SqlDataGridViewModel()
    {
        _dataTable = new DataTable("QUERY");
        FillDataTableWithQuery("SELECT TOP 500 * FROM XUSER");           
    }

    public void FillDataTableWithQuery(string query)
    {
        _dataTable = new DataTable("QUERY");

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(SessionProvider.Instance.currentConnectionString))
            {
                _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
                _adapter.Fill(CurrentDataTable);
            }

            NotifyPropertyChange("CurrentDataTable");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MartuLogger.Instance.Error("Exception in SqlDataGridViewModel :" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

If i don't NotifyPropertyChange after _adapter.Fill, view doesn't refresh. (I've tried to notify in Set CurrentTable, but _adapter.Fill evidently don't call CurrentTable's set method).
Thank you.

Comment: You need to tell your view that table has been updated. Your viewmodel needs to implement NotifyOfPropertyChanged.

Comment: I've tried with INotifyPropertyChanged, but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and call PropertyChanged on set event of datagrid.

public class SqlDataGridViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}

public DataTable CurrentDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _dataTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDataTable");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but isn't NotifyChanged problem... i think that is a problem of AutoGeneratingColumns property!

Comment: Well I think I have figured out the problem. In your View you have set Mode=OneWay. Change it to to TwoWay. I think that it will work.